# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk , Multiple Apps with subdomains on same Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently, I'm doing a deployment of an application in which I'd like to use Amazon Elastic Beanstalk (With Docker) for more automated management of my application. However, my application consists of 3 modules that run on different ports, (the three of them must be publicly accessible).

In a normal deployment in an Apache, I could create virtual hosts with different hostnames and point the DNS to the same server, and Apache would resolve to the correct VirtualHost.

Can I do something like this in Elastic Beanstalk, or with an Application Load Balancer? (Maybe pointing a specific subdomain to a port in the application). The idea would be to have

- mydomain.com - Main Application
- api.mydomain.com - Public API
- clients.mydomain.com - Clients platform

The objective of doing this way is to use the same computing instances for the 3 applications (Reducing costs)

Comment: If the 3 modules are using different ports, I don't think you have to use different domains/subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

Just solved it !, With the Application Load Balancer, I created a rule for hostname and pointed to a specific port in the application. Then, created a DNS A Record in Route 53 for redirecting to the same EB in every route.

Comment: EBS stands for Elastic Block Storage, so your message is a bit confusing. Elastic Beanstalk is just EB.

Comment: I have just done the same but with Nginx as a webserver.